# How to access a forms instance in a modelformset django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In my view I create a formset of photos belonging to a specific article, this works brilliantly, and I am able to render and process the forms. However for the image field I would like to display the already uploaded image. Normally I would access the path through the instance `form.instance.image.get_thumbnail_url` however that doesn't work for the forms in my modelformset - how can i access the instance?

```
...
article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=article_id)
PhotoFormSet = modelformset_factory(Photo)
    formset = PhotoFormSet(queryset=Photo.objects.filter(articles=article_id))
...

...
{% for form in formset.forms %}
     {{ form.instance.image.get_thumbnail_url }}
{% endfor %}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, but it may be that you don't need `instance`:

```
{% for form in formset.forms %}
     {{ form.image.get_thumbnail_url }}
{% endfor %}
```